# node.js mac 10.9 console.log

Tags: node.js, macos

Using node js to move files etc. Using a mac. 
Using a plist so that my files get moved in the background.
Using console.log to track what happens.
Had to move from a mac running 10.6 to a mac running 10.9.
console.log doesn't show up in 10.9 console.

for example this script:

```
    console.log('This works and you are good at stuff.');
```

along with this plist:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.gillstudios.consoleLogTest</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/usr/local/bin/node</string>
            <string>/Library/Scripts/Custom/ConsoleLogTest_001.js</string>
        </array>    
        <key>StartInterval</key>
        <integer>30</integer>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

In 10.6 I get a message every thirty seconds. In 10.9 I get nothing even though when I use the file moving script, files MOVE but I don't get anything in the console.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making my own log and opening it in the console. (the date variables are created in an earlier part of the script)

```
function customLog(logMessage){
    var logfile = '/Library/Logs/AutomationLog/' + year + thisMonth + date + '_automation.txt'
    var logtime = hour + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
    fs.stat(logfile, function(err,stats){
        // if (err) customLog(err); // Throws ENOENT if file doesn't exist.
        if (!err && stats.isFile()){
            fs.appendFileSync(logfile, logtime + ' ' + logMessage + '\n');
        } else {
            fs.writeFile(logfile, logtime + ' ' + logMessage + '\n');
        };
    });
}
```

Then I did a find and replace for console.log/customLog. In the console I went to File/Open (my file). If there is a better way I'd still like to know, but this IS a working solution.